# adb backup hangs and never finishes (Linux)

Tags: adb, backup, linux, 5.1-lollipop

Whenever I run `adb backup` for a full backup, it never finishes. In Terminal, the command hangs indefinitely, and on the device, the backup cycles through a few apps before hanging on one (more about that at the end of this question).

After executing `adb backup`, the backup file on the PC slowly increases in size, but after a while it stops growing. I've let it sit at this point for an hour without any change in the size of the file.

I've tried running `adb backup` 3 different ways (`$ab` is just the name of the backup file):

```
adb backup -f "${ab}" -apk -obb -noshared -all -system
adb backup -f "${ab}" -apk -obb -shared -all -system
adb backup -f "${ab}" -noapk -noobb -noshared -all
```

Not even the last one works. I also tried setting up a desktop backup password under here:

```
Settings > Developer Options > Desktop backup password
```

This didn't help either.

This problem occurs with two different devices, both rooted. Both devices run on Android 5.1.1, so maybe it's a bug with this version of Android? It didn't work on 5.1 either. One of the devices is a Nexus 6 using the official Android 5.1.1 image, so it's not a bug with a custom ROM.

The last few times I tried running `adb backup` on the Nexus 6, I noticed that it started hanging on the same app each time: Titanium Backup. I don't know if this has always been the case; I just noticed it recently.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Also, do any other Linux users have this problem too? If so, it's likely a bug within the `adb` package.

#### EDIT

After running `adb backup` again, it worked! I'm guessing it's because I upgraded my [Nexus device's firmware](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images?hl=en) to a *slightly* newer version: from LMY47Z to LMY48I (both are Android 5.1.1). Maybe it was a bug with the earlier 5.1.1 build, the one before the "Stagefright" fix was added.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to consider a Nandroid backup or apps backup using [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&hl=en)?

Comment: Green i am running 5.1.1 om ny samsung tab and tried your method. I can't even get into the device. I get the now unlock your device message and then the process dies/exits. Trying the same in recovery is the same. I am running kali. It's a toss-up between the distro's adb source/implementation and i am guessing selinux, maybe?

Comment: @Firelord Yeah those are great alternatives so it's not terrible that `adb backup` isn't working. I'm just curious to find out why exactly it doesn't work so I don't have to run `adb pull` on Nandroid or Titanium Backup backups.

Comment: @moonbutt74 I'm using Arch. One of my devices is a Samsung tablet too, the Galaxy Note 10.1 2014 edition. I just had an idea--maybe running it as root would help. (Nice name btw lol)

Comment: GreenRaccoon23, hi , sorry i should have mentioned the root aspect, i was rooted and running as root. I would say it's likely specific to Samsung devices but I don't have a device from another manufacturer to put that against.

Comment: One of mine is a Motorola Nexus 6, so it doesn't look like just a Samsung problem.

Answer (score 3):

*Settings* → *Apps* → *Titanium Backup* → *Force Stop* may allow the ADB backup to continue and finish.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: I had by backup hang on a different app, and killing it in this manner worked for me to allow the backup to continue.